# Вызов PHP-файла в форме без использования атрибута action

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
<form method="post" onload="MyFunction()" id="WidgetForm" onsubmit="return false;"
        action=<?php echo plugins_url('/count.php',__FILE__); ?>>
```

Есть ли способ вызвать другой PHP-файл в `<form>`, не используя `action`?
Мой *count.php* файл не работает без *wp-load.php*.

Answer (score 1):

Если `count.php` не работает без `wp-load.php`, вам понадобится `include`:

```
<?php include '../../../wp-load.php'; ?>
```

Comment: но меня не позволяют так делать...  требуют не вызивать wp-load.php